# Set Serilog minimum level from environment variable

Tags: .net-core, serilog

Is it possible to setup Serilog minimum log level from environment variable?

If I try to configure it like this

```
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": "%LOG_LEVEL%",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "RollingFile",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [v{SourceSystemInformationalVersion}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "pathFormat": "%LOG_FOLDER%/sds-osdr-domain-saga-host-{Date}.log",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 5
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

it returns error

> The value %LOG_LEVEL% is not a valid Serilog level.

Is it possible to propagate log level from environment variable somehow?

Answer (score 8):

I think you are asking about [configuration by environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?tabs=basicconfiguration#configuration-by-environment) which is not specific to serilog.

If the `LOG_LEVEL` is fixed with the specific environment (development, staging or production), you can set the each `LOG_LEVEL` in `appsettings.<EnvironmentName>.json`, and set configuration like this:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .Build();
```

If you need to config the `LOG_LEVEL` from environment variable in docker-compose file or kubernetes deployment file, then you can  read values from environment variables by calling `AddEnvironmentVariables`:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

And set the environment `Serilog:MinimumLevel` in windows or ``Serilog__MinimumLevel` in linux and mac.

Comment: How does this relate to Serilog?

Comment: @jmdon You can use the methods in configuration by environment to set different configuration for Serilog such as log level

Comment: That last row of your answer was the key solution for me!

Answer (score 6):

After some thinking I ended up with the tiny class below

```
public class EnvironmentVariableLoggingLevelSwitch : LoggingLevelSwitch
{
    public EnvironmentVariableLoggingLevelSwitch(string environmentVariable)
    {
        LogEventLevel level = LogEventLevel.Information;
        if (Enum.TryParse<LogEventLevel>(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(environmentVariable), true, out level))
        {
            MinimumLevel = level;
        }
    }
}
```

and using it when configure logger

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(Configuration)
    .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(new EnvironmentVariableLoggingLevelSwitch("%LOG_LEVEL%"))
    .CreateLogger();
```

So, if you don't declare environment variable you still may configure logging level from config file, or override it with environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about using an environment variable in the config file, but it's easy to do from code.  Here is a class that sets the logging level dynamically.  You can read your environment variable and pass to: SetLoggingLevel

```cs
internal static class SerilogConfig
{
    private const int OneDayInMilliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    private static Timer ResetLogLevelTimer = null;

    public static LoggingLevelSwitch LoggingLevel { get; set; }

    static SerilogConfig()
    {
        LoggingLevel = new LoggingLevelSwitch();

        LogEventLevel defaultLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
        bool res = Enum.TryParse<LogEventLevel>(Program.Configuration["DefaultLoggingLevel"], true, out defaultLevel);
        LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel = res ? defaultLevel : LogEventLevel.Information;
    }

    public static void Initialize(string serviceName)
    {
        var logConfig = new LoggerConfiguration();

        logConfig.MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LoggingLevel);
        logConfig.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning);
        logConfig.MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error);

        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Console.WriteLine(msg));

            logConfig.WriteTo.Console();
        }

        Log.Logger = logConfig.CreateLogger();
    }

    public static void SetLoggingLevel(LogEventLevel minimumLevel)
    {
        if (minimumLevel == LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel)
        {
            Log.Verbose("Requested log verbosity level change to the same level. No action taken.");
            return;
        }

        Log.Warning("Changing log verbosity level from {originalLevel} to {newLevel}", LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel.ToString(), minimumLevel.ToString());

        LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel = minimumLevel;

        if (minimumLevel != LogEventLevel.Information)
        {
            int resetLogLevelTimeout = Int32.Parse(Program.Configuration["DetailedLoggingTimeDays"]) * OneDayInMilliseconds;
            ResetLogLevelTimer = new Timer(resetLogLevelTimerCallback, null, resetLogLevelTimeout, Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        else
        {
            if (ResetLogLevelTimer != null)
            {
                ResetLogLevelTimer.Dispose();
                ResetLogLevelTimer = null;
            }
        }
    }
    private static void resetLogLevelTimerCallback(object value)
    {
        if (LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel != LogEventLevel.Information)
        {
            Log.Warning("AUTO RESET: Changing log verbosity level from {0} back to Information", LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel);

            LoggingLevel.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Information;
            ResetLogLevelTimer.Dispose();
            ResetLogLevelTimer = null;
        }
    }
}
```